# Import RPi.GPIO as GPIO ImportError: no module 'RPi'

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi3

I wrote a small text to control my fan that is on my raspberry `pi 3 version B`.

After running the program it came up with an error:

```
'pi@raspberrypi:~/Development $ Sudo python3.5 run-fan.py
 traceback (most recent call last):
 file "run-fan.py", line 9, in <module>
 import PRi.GPIO as GPIO
 ImportError: No module named 'RPi'
```

I don't know to much about Python so I don't know what is wrong

[image: Full Script]

Feel free to ask anything about the script, I thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to upgrade the RPi package by the following command

```
sudo pip install --upgrade RPi.GPIO
```

If you are using python 3 the command should be like this

```
sudo pip3 install --upgrade RPi.GPIO
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to install the module first on your Raspberry. Unfortunately I don't have one to test but according this [link](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/8220/how-to-correctly-install-the-python-rpi-gpio-library) the command for python 3 should be 
 (you may have to load first the package on the raspberry):

```
sudo apt-get -y install python3-rpi.gpio
```

I hope it helps,

Comment: nope  still the same problem, it is still saying 'pi@raspberrypi:~/Development $ Sudo python3.5 run-fan.py
 traceback (most recent call last):
 file "run-fan.py", line 9, in <module>
 import PRi.GPIO as GPIO
 ImportError: No module named 'RPi'                  even after restarting the system

Comment: Can you try answers provided at this [link](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=151273&p=992674).
Sorry I have no RPi to test this :s I only checked on forums

Comment: I saw that post befor and tried it but does not seem to fix it

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is when you using GPIO on raspberry pi, you need add `sudo`.

Answer (score 0):

For me was need to focus on using **python3** with permission of **sudo**
so rember to use sudo with python3

```
sudo python3 filename.py
```

and maybe need to active **SPI** by run through **Terminal**:

> sudo raspi-config

Then

> Interface Options > SPI
> then make sure to be **activated/enabled**